# How to display a flash message by ajax with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, zurb-foundation

I have a modal, but when I close the modal I need to show a flash message to verify that the action was performed, the moment I have this code, but I cant get it, I'm using Foundation but Foundation doesn't have "Toast" or "Alert" like Materialize or Bootstrap, here is my code:

**layouts/alerts.html.erb**

```
<% if notice %>
  <div class="callout small notice">
    <%= notice %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% if alert %>
  <div class="callout small alert">
    <%= alert %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**contact_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="callout">
  <h6>Formulario de contacto</h6>

  <%= form_for @contact, remote: true, authenticity_token: true do |f| %>
    <% if @contact.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@contact.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this @contact from being saved:</h2>

        <ul>
        <% @contact.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Title" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Content", :rows => 10, :cols => 120 %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Send", class: "button" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**create.js.erb**

```
<% if @contact.errors.empty? %>
  $('#exampleModal1').foundation('close');
  $(".notice").html('<%= j render partial: "layouts/alerts" %>');
<% else %>
  $(".alert").html('<%= j render partial: "layouts/alerts" %>');
<% end %>
```

**contact_controller.rb**

```
 def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    @contact.email = current_enterprise.email

    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.save
        ContactMailer.contact_email(@contact).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Contact was successfully created.' }
        format.js { flash[:notice] = "The message was sent" }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @contacts }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

No doubt you have already solved this, but for anyone else who ends up here via Google:

Your code should work, but you need to pass `notice` or `alert` to your `alerts.html.erb` partial.

```
#create.js.erb
<% if @contact.errors.empty? %>
  $('#exampleModal1').foundation('close');
  $(".notice").html('<%= j render partial: "layouts/alerts", locals: { notice: flash[:notice] } %>');
<% else %>
  $(".alert").html('<%= j render partial: "layouts/alerts", locals: { alert: flash[:alert] } %>');
<% end %>
```

You may also need to set a value for `flash[:alert]` in your controller for unsuccessful saves.

Answer (score 0):

I was already using toastr so for me it was as simple as this:

```
# create.js.erb
toastr['info']('<%= j @notice %>');
```